# Knockout radio checked binding

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have some `radio buttons` that use knockout checked bindings.  After making the initial submission with the radios, the template gets the value of the radio and the correct `radio button` is `checked`.  The problem is when I reload the page the previous submission no longer has any `checked radios`.

Here's the code:

```
<input data-bind= "checked: Type, required:Type type="radio" value="1" />
<label>Allowed</label>
<input data-bind= "checked: Type, required: Type, type="radio" value="2" />
<label>Charge</label>
```

In looking at the knockout context plugin with Chrome it shows that the type is set to the original submissions value, however they are still not checked on reload. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain value on a page reload you may want to use local storage.

here is a fiddle when you reload the page it will retain your last checked radio button.

https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/50/

html

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: Type"  value="1" name="myradio" />
<label>Allowed</label>
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: Type"  value="2" name="myradio" />
<label>Charge</label>

<p>
  the value is: <label data-bind="text: Type"></label>
</p>
```

javascript

```
function Model() {
  var self = this;
  this.Type = ko.observable(localStorage.getItem("Type"))
}
var vm = new Model()
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    vm.Type.subscribe(function(newValue) {
       localStorage.setItem("Type", newValue);
   });
});
```